# Automatically redirect with this.props.history.push() on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting up Authentication of a ***React*** App using **Firebase**. One thing that I would like to ensure is that a user once authenticated cannot go back to the `login` page.

Ultimately, I feel this could be done by adding a condition to redirect the user to `/home` when authenticated and visiting the `/login` page, whils when a user is not authenticated they see the `loginForm` with something similar to

```
const LoginPage = () =>
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => authUser
      ? <NavigationAuth />
      : <NavigationNonAuth />
    }
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
```

Whereas `<AuthUserContext.Consumer>` is already working and determining whether the user is authenticated - That works and not my question.

Next if the user is **not authenticated**, they get

```
const NavigationNonAuth = () =>
<NonAuthStyle>
  <LoginForm/>
</NonAuthStyle>
```

and if they are **authenticated** they get

```
const NavigationAuth = () =>
<AuthStyle>
  // What goes here to this.props.history.push("/home")
</AuthStyle>
```

Hopefully that makes sense but **my question is how can I create an event inside `NavigationAuth` to automatically/force redirect the user to `/home`?**

Comment: In the `componentDidMount` method of the child component to be rendered in `NavigationAuth`, write `this.props.location.assign('/home')` (I assume `window.location` is passed as props to the component.)  Ensure to handle the delay during the redirect with a spinner or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router) for your project as this allows you to use some of their components to put routes in place and use redirecting?

Here's an example of some simple routing and using a custom `PrivateRoute` component that takes care of showing authenticated routes or not. You'll need to place this in your main app component.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={NavigationNonAuth} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/auth" component={NavigationAuth} />
  </Switch>
<BrowserRouter/>
```

The `PrivateRoute` component checks if the user is logged in. If not, it will route the user back to the login path by rendering the `<Redirect>` component from React Router, else it'll render the component provided. In this case `NavigationAuth`

Here's a working example to see it all in action. (https://codesandbox.io/s/k5j8wm401v)

Also, to understand React Router v4 and it's components better I found this article pretty helpful. (https://css-tricks.com/react-router-4)

Comment: Thank you - Great answer. I followed a similar https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow scenario and that works great but will be sure to check out your Sandbox for other options.